# Is it possible to obtain last evaluated value in iruby on jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sciruby, iruby

I use iruby on jupyter.  In ipython, one can obtain last evaluated value by local variable `_`.  Is it possible to do somehow achieve it in iruby?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just found another IRuby bug.
Thank you for finding this.

https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby/issues/245